# Why is @DataProvider annotation runs before @BeforeClass in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

Using [TestNG](http://testng.org/), why does the `@DataProvider` run before  `@BeforeClass`?

It seems that sometimes `@DataProvider` runs before `@BeforeClass` and some times not?

Anybody knowing the reason?

Comment: What kind of testing framework are you using?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but she did actually say in the tag: TestNG: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html  The tag **looks** like "testing", but in fact is "testng". Me, I'd've put that in the question itself for clarity. (And so I did.)

Comment: @T.J - Damn - thats exactly the mistake i made. The tag sure looked like "testing" to me! Good catch!! My bad!!

Comment: anyone met the situation before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the way it's implemented today, is this a problem for you?

Comment: Hi Cedric,Thanks for answering. I wanna some methods run before DataProvider and run only once. what can I do?

Comment: How about using a @BeforeSuite?

Comment: It will run before @BeforeSuite as well.

Answer (score 3):

Please find the sequence of execution below:

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeTest
@BeforeClass
@DataProvider
@BeforeMethod
@AfterMethod
@AfterClass
@AfterTest
@AfterSuite
```

Answer (score 1):

> @BeforeClass

`BeforeClass annotation` Method runs only once before the first test method. The Current Class method will be one from which it is invoked.

> @DataProvider

`DataProvider annotation` method returns an Object[ ][ ] type value, where each Object[ ] can be assigned as the parameter of the test method that wants to receive the data from this DataProvider annotation method.

```
public class TestNgDataProviderExample {
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("in beforeClass");
    }
    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public void instanceDbProvider(int p1, String p2) {
        System.out.println("DataProvider Data(" + p1 + ", " + p2 + ")");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][] {{5, "five"}, {6, "six"}};
    }
}
```

Output:

- in beforeClass
- DataProvider Data(5, five)
- DataProvider Data(6,
  six)