# Maven surefire plugin is not picking up groups options for testng

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a testng case with following annotation -

`@Test(groups="groupA", dataProvider="DataSet1")`

But when I trigger following maven command it does not execute the test -

`mvn test -Dgroups=groupA`

All I see in console is this -

```
...
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ abc-proj ---

-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.733 sec -      in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

But when I simply run `mvn test` it executes the test. Not sure why it is behaving like this. I am using Surefire plugin version `2.19.1` and testng version `6.9.9`. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT** I am not using testng.xml and just out of curiosity I tried same thing in a small project -> it works. In that project I created a sample class -

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTest {

    @Test(groups = "groupA")
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("Inside A");
    }

    @Test(groups = "groupB")
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("Inside B");
    }

}
```

And the `pom.xml` is -

```
... 
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here the command `mvn test -Dgroups=groupA` works fine!

**EDIT2** When I removed the `dataProvider` annotation I noticed some different result, console now says -

`Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1`

Comment: You must be aware that the groups are case sensitive so you have to give `mvn test -Dgroups=abc` instead of `mvn test -Dgroups=ABC`....furthermore if you define a data provider which does not exist the test will not being executed...cause it does not exist....

Comment: I have taken care of case sensitivity as well as dataprovider. Looks like grouping with dataProvider does not work well in testng and maven combo. Saw something related here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595654/testng-is-ignoring-parameterized-tests-with-dataprovider-maven-intellij

Comment: A dataProvider works very well if you have given a dataprovider and of course you have to implement one......and testng works very well with Maven...I'm not sure what your exact problem is..? That tests will not being executed if you give a dataprovider which does not exist?

Comment: @khmarbaise I think I have provided enough information regarding my problem. Sorry if it still does not make any sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause of this issue. Here `testng` is running `@DataProvider` method [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775974/in-testng-why-the-dataprovider-run-before-beforeclass), even before running `@BeforeClass` method and I have a dependency between these two (I assumed @BeforeClass will run first). This, however, does not cause any problem when I run all the tests at once but becomes evident when I try to run test selectively based on the `groups`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to group your tests into surefire configuration to do that:-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <groups>ABC,XYZ</groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then execute

```
mvn test -Dgroups=ABC
```

Comment: @takias Does your project rely on the `testng.xml` in that case? If yes, do update the question with your current plugin config and xml.

Comment: I am not using testng.xml. My intention is to use the `groups` option to filter any test during execution.

Comment: @takias Not sure how else do you wish to group your tests and let maven be aware of it.

Comment: I thought `surefire-testng` takes care of that. Even I have tried it successfully on a small project. Where I only have the following in pom `<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.9.9</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>`
And running `mvn test -Dgroups=ABC` works there without having a testng.xml

Comment: @takias Please edit and update the question with any useful information. Also with the project that you say was running fine.

Comment: edited my question, let me know if you need any other info

Answer (score 0):

```
    This works for me: 
    Tests:
         @Test(groups = "Regression")
         public void testOne(){
         System.out.println("Regression");}
    
         @Test(groups = "Functional")
         public void testTwo() {
         System.out.println("Functional");
         }
    
    use this in pom.xml
    
        <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>run.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>'



run.xml file: 
   

     <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    
        <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
        <test name="TestingGroups" >
            <classes>
                <class name="test.GroupsTesting"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
        </suite>'

command to run Functional test cases :mvn test -Dgroups=Functional
```